# REST style resources using tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using django and let's say have two models, `Comment` & `News`. Now, `Comment` has a field `news = models.ForeignKey(News)`, i.e. each news has some comments associated with it. REST way of `GET`ing these resources would be `/api/v1/news/news-id/comments`. But how do I specify such url structure in `tastypie`.

Currently in my `api.py`, I have

```
class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    news = fields.ForeignKey(NewsResource, 'news')
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'comments'
```

so, I have to access comments here: `/api/v1/comments/`. How do I achieve what I want?